# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just switched from using a local copy of the minified version of d3.v3 to the development version. It worked fine when using the minified version, but using my local copy of http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js gives me the error in the title, referencing this line:

```
var € = Math.PI, µ = 1e-6, d3_radians = € / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / €;
```

When I include the hosted file, it works fine.

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com - and more importantly - where and how are you getting this error? Can you please post the relevant code?

Comment: @limelights Come one, it's only 8000 lines of code. Surely you can go through that and figure it out?

Comment: :D yes, I have done so and the error is on line 45

Comment: line 17 of d3.v3.js.
in my text editor, that line renders as
var π = Math.PI, ε = 1e-6, d3_radians = π / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / π;

I get the error serving the html page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'> 
<script src="d3.v3.js"></script>
</head><body></body>
</html>

I think this was a valid question, closed to quickly.

Comment: Added the utf-8 byte order mark to the top of d3.v3.js and the error went away. Hope that helps, Wex.

Comment: @Ed. - How exactly do you do that? I'm pretty sure my file is already utf-8

Comment: Apparently it is also important how the local copy was obtained. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Upgrading-to-3.0 Quote: "If you’d prefer to host your own copy of D3, download the zipball or clone the repository and pull out the contained d3.js and d3.min.js. Don’t copy-and-paste the JavaScript contents from your browser; that can corrupt UTF-8 characters."

Comment: @nautat - I took mine from the zip.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The problem is that you are serving D3 with the ISO-8859-1 character encoding (often the browser default), whereas D3 must be served with UTF-8 encoding. Typically this happens because you are missing a meta tag at the top of the loading HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

The meta-specified charset is required because [d3js.org](http://d3js.org) is served by [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/) and does not specify a charset in the Content-Type response header. The charset is therefore inferred from the loading HTML document.

If you prefer, you can specify a charset attribute on the script tag. Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing, as the cached copy will retain the character encoding from when it was originally accessed:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The error does not occur with the minified version because the variable names are replaced with ASCII equivalents. (I don't recall offhand if UTF-8 characters in format strings are likewise replaced with escape sequences, but I still recommend serving D3 as UTF-8 in all cases.)

Encoding problems can also happen if you downloaded D3 by viewing the source in your browser and then using copy-paste, which is why I recommend downloading [d3.v3.zip](http://d3js.org/d3.v3.zip).

Comment: How can I do the same if I use npm to get d3?

Answer (score 3):

it is definitely an encoding issue, try to focus on that.

Opening with Chrome the link you posted (http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js) i see that double-byte characters too:

```
 var Ï€ = Math.PI, Îµ = 1e-6, d3_radians = Ï€ / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / Ï€;
```

if you barely save the file with "save page as..." and you open it with an editor like Sublime Text (http://www.sublimetext.com/) it works fine and it shows:

```
var π = Math.PI, ε = 1e-6, d3_radians = π / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / π;
```

i tried to use this downloaded file with a projects of mine and it's all right.